# Does `sethostname()` send a new value of `nodename` from the local machine to a DNS server to update the DNS record for the local machine?

Tags: c, linux, dns, hostname

From The Linux Programming Interface

> ```
> struct utsname {
>     char sysname[_UTSNAME_LENGTH];      /* Implementation name */
>     char nodename[_UTSNAME_LENGTH];     /* Node name on network */
>     char release[_UTSNAME_LENGTH];      /* Implementation release level */
>     char version[_UTSNAME_LENGTH];      /* Release version level */
>     char machine[_UTSNAME_LENGTH];      /* Hardware on which system
>                                            is running */
> #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE                      /* Following is Linux-specific */
>     char domainname[_UTSNAME_LENGTH];   /* NIS domain name of host */
> #endif
> };
> ```
>
> The `nodename` field returns the value that was set using the
>   `sethostname()` system call (see the manual page for details of this
>   system call). Often, this name is something like the hostname prefix
>   from the system’s DNS domain name.
>
> The `domainname` field returns the value that was set using the
>   `setdomainname()` system call (see the manual page for details of this
>   system call). This is the Network Information Services (NIS) domain
>   name of the host (which is not the same thing as the host’s DNS domain
>   name).

Is `nodename` used by some DNS server for resolving the hostname of the current machine to its IP address? If yes, which DNS server is that?

Does `sethostname()` send a new value of `nodename` from the local machine to the DNS server to update the hostname in the DNS record for the local machine?

Similar questions for `domainname` and `setdomainname()`, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, `sethostname` mere updates a name in the kernel, and this part of the kernel knows nothing at all about DNS.

What can happen is that if you use glibc and have certain [NSS modules](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extending-NSS.html) (such as [`myhostname` from systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/nss-myhostname/nss-myhostname.c)), they might react automatically to the host name change in the kernel.  This affects name resolution (mapping from names to IP addresses), but does not involve DNS, either.

Comment: Thanks.  (1) "This affects name resolution (mapping from names to IP addresses)" how is that done? (2) What does " Node name on network" mean for `nodename`?

Comment: I added a few links. Basically, glibc inherited the NSS plugin framework from Solaris. *Node name on network* is just a comment. The key point is that `sethostname` affects the `nodename` field.